# Options to forward vm to internet via ssh tunnel

Tags: networking, iptables, kvm-virtualization, ssh-tunnel, qemu

Want to give vm in qemu/kvm internet access but only via a port i can forward to ssh tunnel.

qemu -> host (already established) ssh tunnel on port 8083 -> ssh proxy -> www

ports for browsers and services can be forwarded, how to forward vm? I can forward browser traffic thru tunnel on port 8083 to ssh server on port 22 then out to the internet.  Instead of forwarding browser traffic want to forward qemu traffic.

1. Dont want to use system wide vpn
2. Is creating a bridge the correct solution
3. Are iptables on qemu host/vm the correct solution
4. setup a ssh tunnel : vm -> host -> ssh proxy server -> www

Answer (score 0):

for anyone getting a brain hickup like i did when i posted this.

If VM is connecting successfully to internet -> install ssh -> Tunnel directly out from vm bypassing host or local network except as the rails for the ssh tunnel

```
# ssh -N -D 8083 remotehost-username@1.1.1.1 -p 22
```